# Method prints table incorrectly

Tags: java

I was wondering if someone could help me with a small problem I'm having.

I am trying to print out an array of 100 items, every row needs 10 items, after which it starts a new row. I have done this successfully, however, every row in every column displays the same number. For example. My output would be:

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
```

When it should be appearing as something along the lines of:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
```

Here is the following method I am using to print the table:

```
public static void printTable(int[] emirps) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            // After 10 go to a new line
            System.out.printf("%d\t", emirps[i]);
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

If anyone can help me pinpoint where I have goofed I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Ah, I forgot to try that. Give me a moment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are printing the same `emirps[i]` each time through the inner loop. There are a couple of ways around this. Here's one:

```
public static void printTable(int[] emirps) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i += 10) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            // After 10 go to a new line
            System.out.printf("%d\t", emirps[i + j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Here's another (not very elegant):

```
public static void printTable(int[] emirps) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
        System.out.printf("%d\t", emirps[i]);
        if (i % 10 == 9) {
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not using the `j` index anywhere in this code.

Here is how you should print:

`System.out.printf("%d\t", emirps[i+j]);`

Notice how in the print statement you are now using both the `i` and `j` indices.
Also, to get your row offset working correctly, you should be incrementing `i` by 10 at each step of the loop.

Alternatively, declare `emirps` as a 2-dimensional array.  Then the signature of `printTable()` would be:

`public static void printTable(int[][] emirps)`

In that setup, here is how you would print:

`System.out.printf("%d\t", emirps[i][j]);`

So in the first setup, `i+j` together index into a 1-D array.  In the second setup, `i` is the row and `j` is the column, indexing together into a 2-D array.  It looks like you're doing a 1-D array but this other example is for your future reference.

Comment: That doesn't quite do it. The outer loop variable needs to increment by 10, not 1.

Comment: Good catch - I'll fix it.  Thx.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like homework, so instead of giving you the answer, here's a hint:

For the first iteration of the first loop, i = 0. When this is the case, you increment j from 0 to 9. Note that i stays the same throughout. This is when you print your first line.

Once you're through with the second for loop, i increases by 1 to, and now i = 1. Again, you increment j from 0 to 9, and i stays at 1. This is when you print your second line.

This repeats 100 times, as i goes from 0 to 99.

There are 2 ways of approaching this:

1. Use one for loop, and figure out when to print an end-of-line character.
2. Use two for loops, each going up to 10. Figure out your index by simple multiplication and addition.

You should try and implement both methods. It'll help you understand loops better.

Answer (score 0):

Use the modulo operator. Every time your number can be divided by 10 without a remainder, you can make a new line because you have filled up the row. You obtain the remainder using the 'modulo operator' which is the percent (%) sign. It can be used like /, except that rather than the quotient being the result, the remainder of the division operation is the result.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        if (i != 0 && i % 10 == 0)
        {
            builder.append('\n');
        }
        builder.append(i + " ");
    }
    System.out.println(builder.toString());
}
```

Prints out:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 
20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 
30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 
40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 
50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 
60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 
70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 
80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 
90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99
```

Comment: For homework questions, try not to give the actual answer. Instead, guide the OP in the right direction. This helps them learn instead of just using what you gave them.

Comment: @KshitijMehta - There's nothing to suggest that this is homework.

Comment: @KshitijMehta It's not tagged with homework, so it's an assumption. But I understand. I tried to make it informative by kind of explaining the use of the modulo, which doesn't show up all that much.